# Response format specification in ASP.NET MVC 3 Routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm creating an API for a website. I'm using ASP.Net MVC 3 and I'm trying to create routes that support an optional .format parameter. So the client app could request /user/post.json, /user/posts.xml or just /users/posts
   I was able to make the .json or .xml ending url's work using the following route:

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
        "no_params", _
        "{controller}/{action}.{format}", _
        New With {.action = "Index", .format = UrlParameter.Optional} _
    )
```

But I couldn't make the url without the .format parameter (/user/posts) work alongside. Can anyone help me out here with some example?

thanks!

Comment: what version of iis are you using?

Comment: the . is probably causing you issues here. Why not create another route that doesn't have the . and add it after the no_params route. That way if one with a . arrives it will be processed by the no_params route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the dot:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "no_params", _
    "{controller}/{action}{format}", _
    New With {.action = "Index", .format = UrlParameter.Optional}, _
    New With {.format = "(\.json|\.xml)?"} _
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would say that the client can specify the type using 'content-type' rather than on the url :)

But to get it working you will need to register another route without the format since using /user/posts does not contain a period (.) it cannot match the route you specified.

`routes.MapRoute("no_params_no_format", "{controller}/{action}", _`

```
    New With {.action = "Index" } _
)
```

HTH